# Is it possible to associate a contact with a company name?

Tags: salesforce

I am looking for a "company name" field in the contact edit panel but I can't find it.

Is is even possible to indicate what would be the contact's company name?

Thanks for your help

Comment: nevermin, the company name field is "Account name"

Comment: Vincent, please add an answer how you found on the name of the field, and accept it, or delete the question, or accept the given answer by toufik_at so that it does not stay here as unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

You can link your contact to an account using the field "**account name**" (lookup), but if you want a "company name" field you can create a custom field, go to Setup->App setup-> Customize-> Contacts -> fields, and then scroll down a little bit, you find "custom fields and relationships", click the new button, and then add your "**company name" field,i hope this helps :)